# Zoom-out from web view to fit content

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I am trying to make my `WebView` automatically zoom out when the content is too wide to be displayed without a scroll bar.

I have wrapped my `WebView` in a `ScrollBar`, and set the `ZoomFactor` based on the ScrollViewers `ViewPortWidth` property divided by the actual Web Page width (calculated via JavaScript).

It is almost working, but after the ScrollViewer has zoomed out, a part of the right hand side of the web page is not displayed - it looks like the missing part corresponds to the part that was not visible when it wasn't zoomed out.  It's almost like the Web Page is not being redrawn when it is zoomed out.

Here is my code:

.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Name="WebScrollViewer">
        <WebView x:Name="ContentView" 
                 NavigationFailed="contentView_NavigationFailed" 
                 DOMContentLoaded="contentView_LoadCompleted" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

.cs

```
 private void contentView_LoadCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args) 
{
    // ask the content its width
    var widthString = ContentView.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { "document.body.scrollWidth.toString()" });
    int width;

    if (!int.TryParse(widthString, out width))
        throw new Exception(string.Format("failure/width:{0}", widthString));

    // ask the content its height
    var heightString = ContentView.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { "document.body.scrollHeight.toString()" });
    int height;
    if (!int.TryParse(heightString, out height))
        throw new Exception(string.Format("failure/height:{0}", heightString));

    if (WebScrollViewer.ViewportWidth < width)
    {

        // resize the webview to the content
        ContentView.Width = width;
        ContentView.Height = height;

        var zoomFactor = WebScrollViewer.ViewportWidth / width;

        WebScrollViewer.ZoomToFactor((float)zoomFactor);
        WebScrollViewer.InvalidateScrollInfo();

    }

}
```

I've been stuck on this for a while, and have tried all kinds of variations of the above, all with the same problem.

Am I missing something obvious?  Or is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it sorted finally.  The default value for `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` for the `ScrollViewer` is `Disabled`.  I guess that when you can't scroll horizontally and the contents of the ScrollViewer is wider than the `ViewPort`, they figure that there is no need to render what cannot be viewed.

So, the fix was easy in the end, just modify the .xaml

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer Name="WebScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <WebView x:Name="ContentView" 
                 NavigationFailed="contentView_NavigationFailed" 
                 DOMContentLoaded="contentView_LoadCompleted" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```